# ionic 2 http.post cannot waiting response >= 7 seconds

Tags: php, apache, angular, ionic-framework

sorry if my language is not good.

i have a ionic app, this app send data with angular http.post to server my company, this is my script on server :

```
<?php
set_time_limit(120);
ini_set("max_execution_time",120);
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
require_once("menu.php");
class serviceController extends menu
{
    private $clientInput;
    public function __construct($clientInput){
        $this->clientInput = $clientInput;
        $this->Controller();
    }
    private function getMenu($packageName){
        parent::__construct($packageName);
        echo json_encode(parent::menu());
    }
    private function Controller(){
        $Decode = json_decode($this->clientInput);
        if($Decode->id=="getMenu"){
            $this->getMenu($Decode->packageName);
        }else if($Decode->id=="Development"){
            sleep(15);
            echo '{"status":"1","info":"Success"}';
        }else{
            switch($Decode->packageName){
                case "com.guava.manis.mobile.payment":{
                    $this->doRequest("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/multiflat_new.jsp");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    private function doRequest($target){
        $ch     = curl_init($target);
        $input  = str_replace(':"",',':"-",',str_replace(':false,',':"-",',str_replace(':0,',':"-",',$this->clientInput)));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$input);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type:application/json'));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $finalResponse = rtrim("1",$response);
        echo $finalResponse;
    } 
}
$clientInput = file_get_contents("php://input");
new serviceController($clientInput);
```

this is my script on my ionic app :

```
httpPOST(){
    var request = JSON.stringify(this.finalREQ);
    console.log("httpPOST request : "+request);
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.postUrl,request,options).timeout(50000)
}
```

when i send data json to server with field 'id' is 'Development' my script will be sleep 15 seconds, the problem is ionic app not receive response from server, but if i change sleep <=7 seconds it's works, my question is how to create ionic app can wait response >=7 seconds ?, but if my scripts on server i move to localhost, dan i send data to localhost it's works perfectly, where the problem ?, on my server scripts, my ionic app scripts, or on my configuration of apache ?